SQL column filter
I have this SQL code:
SELECT DISTINCT
    PA.Serie + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, PA.Numero) Partida,
    PA.Id_Cultivo
    --Informacion Familia Origen,
    (SELECT _FA.Nombre AS Familia
     FROM FamiliasArticulo _FA
     INNER JOIN Articulos _A ON _A.Id_Familia = _FA.Id
                             AND _A.Id = APNS.Id_Articulo
     WHERE _FA.Id_FamiliaSuperior IS NOT NULL) AS FamiliaOrigen

    -- ------
    -- - Is it possible to filter by `FamiliaOrigen` here?
    -- ------

FROM
    AlbaranesVenta as AV
INNER JOIN
    LineasAlbaranVenta AS LAV ON LAV.Id_AlbaranVenta = AV.Id
INNER JOIN
    LineasAlbaranVentaArticulo AS LAVA ON LAVA.Id_LineaAlbaranVenta = LAV.id
INNER JOIN
    Articulos Producto ON Producto.Id = LAVA.Id_Articulo
                       AND Producto.TipoArticulo = 2
INNER JOIN
    LineasAlbaranVentaComercializacionArticulo LAVCA ON LAVCA.Id_LineaAlbaranVentaArticulo = LAV.Id
INNER JOIN
    LineasAlbaranVentaComercializacionArticulo_NumerosSerie LAVCA_NS ON LAVCA_NS.Id_LineasAlbaranVentaComercializacionArticulo = LAV.Id
INNER JOIN
    ArticulosNumeroSerieComposicionVariable ANSCV ON ANSCV.ID = LAVCA_NS.id_numerosserie
INNER JOIN
    ArticulosNumerosSerie ANS ON ANS.Id = ANSCV.Id_ArticuloNumeroSerie
INNER JOIN 
    ArticulosNumeroSerieComposicionVariable_DatosOrigen ANSCV_DO ON ANSCV_DO.Id_ArticulosNumeroSerieComposicionVariable = ANSCV.Id
FULL JOIN
    ArticulosPartida APNS ON APNS.Id = ANSCV_DO.Id_DatosOrigen
INNER JOIN
    Partidas PA ON PA.Id = APNS.Id_Partida
                AND PA.Id_PartidaSectorAgrario IS NOT NULL
HAVING 
    FamiliaOrigen IS NOT NULL

I get an error:

FamiliaOrigen name is not valid

Do you know How can I filter by FamiliaOrigen IS NOT NULL?

Why are there two sql statement fragments in your question? What is the bottom one meant to represent? As for the subquery in your first sql fragment, that WHERE clause is fine. I have my doubts about the correlation in the inner join criteria, but that might be ok. It's all just strange though. Can you post your full SQL statement without including any other fragments, or explain what we are looking at better?

also we need to know which database system you are using see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

JOIN the subquery, and put the condition in the main WHERE clause.

You would have to repeat the correlated subquery expression in a WHERE clause, or nest the entire thing in another subquery and filter at the outer level.
When you have to repeat expressions like this, I often find it useful to do a lateral join (APPLY) instead.
So instead of this:
SELECT column,
     ( <subquery> ) column2
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON ...
WHERE ( <subquery> ) = 'value'

I might do this:
SELECT column, sq.column2
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON ...
APPLY ( <subquery> ) sq
WHERE sq.column2 = 'value'

But you can also do this:
SELECT column, column2
FROM (
    SELECT column,
         ( <subquery> ) column2
    FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON ...
) t
WHERE t.column2 = 'value'


Thank you for your support.
@Joel Coehorn you were right, I've add:
    select *
from (

Previously the origintal statement like this:
select *
from (
select 
    DISTINCT
             PA.Serie + '/' + CONVERT(varchar,
    PA.Numero) Partida,
    PA.Id_Cultivo
    --Informacion Familia Origen
               ,
    (
    select 
                _FA.Nombre as Familia
            from
                FamiliasArticulo _FA
            inner join Articulos _A on
                _A.Id_Familia = _FA.Id
                and _A.Id = APNS.Id_Articulo
                where _FA.Id_FamiliaSuperior is not null
                     ) as FamiliaOrigen
from
    AlbaranesVenta as AV

Calling at the end of the code to :
) t
    where t.FamiliaOrigen is not NULL 

Thank you for your suppot, good idea.
